# QDirIterator, reset iterator, set new path

Tags: qt, iterator, qt5

I'm interesting in resetting `QDirIterator` by setting a new path.
eg

```
    QDirIterator it(path, QStringList() << "*", QDir::Files);

    while (it.hasNext())
    { 
         // do job
    }

    it = QDirIterator(another_path, QStringList() << "*", QDir::Files));

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
         // iterate another directory
    }
```

This example throw compilation error: "Overload resolution selected deleted operator '='"

Is there a way to set a new path for an iterator ?

Thanks.

PS: I'm talking about Qt5

Comment: Why do you want to reset? Why don't you create a new object? `QDirIterator it(another_path, QStringList() << "*", QDir::Files)`

Comment: because I already has `it` in this code scope. I know that there are easy workarounds like other name or extra braces reassignment seems pretty good here.

Comment: QDirIterator has no copy constructor, so reassignment fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to reuse the same `QDirIterator` just use multiple instances but scope them accordingly...

```
for (QDirIterator it(path, QStringList() << "*", QDir::Files); it.hasNext(); ) {

    /*
     * Do job.
     */
}

for (QDirIterator it(another_path, QStringList() << "*", QDir::Files); it.hasNext(); ) {

    /*
     * Iterate another directory.
     */
}
```